# How to force running sh file without use of terminal

Tags: command-line, mendeley

I have `mendeleydesktop` python script file which run menedeley software GUI on my ubuntu 16 machine. I run the following command to allow execution `sudo chmod +x mendelelydesktop` then I made a symbolic link on my desktop  `ln -s mendeleydesktop ~/Desktop/mendeleydesktop`. Running `./mendeleydesktop` from termianl is OK but double clicking or using Dash send file to gedit for editing.

N.B: Allowing file execution through file proprieties don't solve the problem.

How to force running mendeley through double clicking directly without need to run terminal so I don't have to run terminal each time I run mendeley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open nautilus, then go to:

```
Edit > Preferences > Behavior tab
```

On **Executable Text Files** section, check **Run executable files when they are opened**.

[image]